# Set associated form for custom element like form attribute for the input element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Due to the layout of my page I would like to place a custom element outside of a form.

Can I make something like `<my-custom-element form="foo">` work?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on what `<my-custom-element>` outputs.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but browsers ignore tags that are not understood, so you could define `<my-custom-element> <form name="foo"> ... </form> </my-custom-element>`

Answer (score -1):

Presuming you want the submit button to return the value of your element even though it is outside the form. This is one way, there are many more (including using the function here called addExtras() to dynamically append your external name/value pair(s) to the form).

```
<my-custom-element> <input name="custom" id="custom" value="foo"></my-custom-element>

<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return addExtras()" method="post">
  <input type="hidden"" name="customItem" id="customItem" />
  <input name="anotherField" value="india" />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function addExtras() {
    document.getElementById("customItem").value = document.getElementById("custom").value;
    return true;
  }

  // ==========================================================
  //Code to display the submitted items, and prevent submission for test purposes
  //Not needed for production
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    //prevent the normal submission of the form
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("myForm").elements.length; i++) {
      var e = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[i];
      console.log(e.name, e.value)
    }
  });
</script>
```